# Slice XMLList instead of Array

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, actionscript-3, slice, xmllist

How would I get a range of items from my xmllist similar to the slice method for an array?

slice(startIndex,endIndex);

I am trying something like this:

```
            var tempXMLList:XMLList = new XMLList();

            for( var i:int = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
                tempXMLList += originalList[i];
            }
```

But I am getting an error that it can't convert originalList[i]

--- Update ---

I used Timofei's function and it worked perfectly.

```
private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
{
    return xmllist.(childIndex() >= startIndex && childIndex() <= endIndex);
}
```

However, when I use an xmllist that was already been filtered, it breaks.

```
filteredData = filteredData.(team == "Ari");

trace("filteredData.length(): " + filteredData.length().toString());
pData = SliceXMLList(filteredData, startIndex, endIndex);
trace("start: " + startIndex.toString() + " end: " + endIndex.toString());
trace("pdata length: " + pData.length().toString());
```

*output*

```
filteredData.length(): 55
start: 0 end: 55
pdata length: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use e4x.

```
private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
{
    return xmllist.(childIndex() >= startIndex && childIndex() <= endIndex);
}
```

**Update:**

There's a problem, if you're going to use this function after some e4x-sorting, 'cause the childIndex() function returns the old values of the nodes' indexes and it cannot be changed. So, I have another idea:

```
private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
{
    for (var i : int = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++)
        xmllist[i].@realIndex = i;
    xmllist =  xmllist.(@realIndex >= startIndex && @realIndex <= endIndex);
    for (i = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++)
        delete xmllist[i].@realIndex;
    return xmllist;
}
```

or just

```
private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
{
    var newXMLList : XMLList = new XMLList();
    var currIndex : int = 0;
    for (var i : int = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        newXMLList[currIndex++] = xmllist[i];
    return newXMLList;
}
```

This is the best variant, i think. Of course one-line e4x statement is much more elegant, but unfortunately it's not reusable.

Comment: Actually, I am getting weird results when my original xmllist comes from another list that was filtered.  I think maybe the index is not updated?

Comment: Could you show the whole code, please? filderedData is an XMLList, that is the result of slicing, am I right?

Comment: You're right, the problem is about childIndex(), 'cause they do not change. Let me think, what we can do...

Comment: How about assign it to a new xmllist?  filteredData = new XMLList(filteredData);

Comment: That didn't work.  Some sort of copy that creates new childIndexs?   Or maybe your function can use something other than childindex.  Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: If childIndex() doesn't work as we wish, let's do our own one: `private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
        {
            for (var i : int = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++)
                xmllist[i].@realIndex = i;
            return xmllist.(@realIndex >= startIndex && @realIndex <= endIndex);
        }`  The problem now is that I have no idea, how to remove the attribute "realIndex" :)

Comment: private function SliceXMLList(xmllist : XMLList, startIndex : int, endIndex : int) : XMLList
        {
            for (var i : int = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++)
                xmllist[i].@realIndex = i;
            xmllist =  xmllist.(@realIndex >= startIndex && @realIndex <= endIndex);
            for (i = 0; i < xmllist.length(); i++)
                delete xmllist[i].@realIndex;
            return xmllist;
        }

Comment: An elegant solution and a robust one.  Thanks so much for all of your work.  I am sure this solution will help a lot of people.  Adobe can incorporate your XMLList slice in a future release.  Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you expect it to work, but you could iterate through all children, and save each one into an array, and then trim them that way

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the correct syntax?  I added code above.